# Chart.js: how to order the tool tips in the graph

Tags: javascript, charts

I generate a graph where I have 3 groups of data:

- bottom
- middle
- top

Each bar has the top values at the top of the bar, then the middle value and then the bottom value.

When Chart.js displays the tooltip, I have first the bottom value, then the middle and the the top. So, it is the opposite of the order in the bar.

[image]

To display the values I added this code

```
var stackedBarChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'label',
        callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": " + 
                       tooltipItem.yLabel;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to order the list of tool tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the tooltip `label` callback, we can choose any index to display.
in your callback, you're displaying the index passed to the callback.

```
tooltipItem.datasetIndex
```

instead, let's display the reverse order...

```
data.datasets.length - 1 - tooltipItem.datasetIndex
```

but we will also have to add the callback for `labelColor`,
to display the correct color box for the specific label.

see following working snippet...

```js
var chart_canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var stackedLine = new Chart(chart_canvas, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A'],
    fill: true,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Low',
        data: [67.8],
        backgroundColor: '#D6E9C6'
      },
      {
        label: 'Moderate',
        data: [20.7],
        backgroundColor: '#FAEBCC'
      },
      {
        label: 'High',
        data: [11.4],
        backgroundColor: '#EBCCD1'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'label',
      callbacks: {
        labelColor: function (tooltipItem, data) {
          return {backgroundColor: data.data.datasets[data.data.datasets.length - 1 - tooltipItem.datasetIndex].backgroundColor};
        },
        label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
          return data.datasets[data.datasets.length - 1 - tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": " + data.datasets[data.datasets.length - 1 - tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the solution. It is working perfectly